# Double Printing - C

Tags: c, null, return, printf

I am reading from a file, however if it doesn't exist is meant to print 'Read error' but for some reason it is printing read error twice and I don't know why

```
int loadFlights(char flightDatabase[50], int totalflights,  flight_t f[MAX_NUM_FLIGHTS]) 
{
    int counter;

    FILE *fp; 
    fp = fopen("database.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL) { /************************statement with problem*/
        printf("Read error\n");
        return 1;
    }   
    fscanf(fp, "%d",  &totalflights);
    if (totalflights > 5) {
        totalflights = 5;
    }
    for(counter = 0; counter <= totalflights-1; counter++) 
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %d %d %s %d %d %d %d", f[counter].flightcode, 
        &f[counter].departure_dt.month, &f[counter].departure_dt.date, 
        &f[counter].departure_dt.hour, &f[counter].departure_dt.minute, 
        f[counter].arrival_citycode, &f[counter].arrival_dt.month, 
        &f[counter].arrival_dt.date, &f[counter].arrival_dt.hour, 
        &f[counter].arrival_dt.minute);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return totalflights;
}
```

I've tried putting an `if` statement around the Read Error if statement saying if its already been printed don't print again however it still seems to be printing.

```
int main(void)
{
    flight_t f[MAX_NUM_FLIGHTS];
    int totalflights = 0, menu;
    char flightDatabase[50] = "database.txt";
    while (menu != 5)
    {
        print_Menu();
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        while ((menu < 0) || (menu > 5)) {
            printf("Invalid choice\n");
            print_Menu();
            scanf("%d", &menu);
        }
        if (menu == 1) 
        {
            addFlight(f, totalflights);
            totalflights++; 
        }
        else if (menu == 2) 
        {
            displayFlight(f, totalflights); 
        }
        else if (menu == 3) 
        {
            saveFlight(f, flightDatabase,  totalflights);
        }
        else if (menu == 4) 
        {
            loadFlights(flightDatabase, totalflights, f);
            totalflights = loadFlights(flightDatabase, totalflights,f);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code where I call on the function.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your variable `menu` starts out *uninitialized* which means it has an *indeterminate* value (which will seem random). Don't use it without initialization.

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) because then the problem should be very obvious. Hint: How many times do you call `loadFlights`?

Comment: From this line: `loadFlights(flightDatabase, totalflights, f);
        totalflights = loadFlights(flightDatabase, totalflights,f);` it looks like you're calling `loadFlights` twice, which means if the file doesn't exist, would give you your double message. (It's like the fourth line from the botton of the code you posted)

Comment: You are calling your function `loadFlights` twice. Each time, the file doesn't exists, so you're printing the error twice.

Comment: Aren't I calling loadFlights once, then assigning the returned value of loadFlights to totalflights once? How would I fix this

Comment: @AngusRyan When you write `loadflights(...)` you're calling `loadflights` and throwing the return value away.  On the next line, when you write `totalflights = loadflights(...)`, you're calling it a second time, and assigning the return value to `totalflights`.

Comment: okay perfect it works now, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

This is where the problem is:

```
// Some code

else if (menu == 4) 
{
    loadFlights(flightDatabase, totalflights, f);
    totalflights = loadFlights(flightDatabase, totalflights,f);
}
```

These are two consecutive calls to `loadFlights` while the first call doesn't catch the return value. You can get rid of the first one and it should behave the way you expect it to.

Additionally, I see a problem:

```
while (menu != 5)
```

At this point, `menu` is uninitialised, will hold a random value. You might want to either initialise it to zero or 5 or whatever is legal for that data type.

> I've tried putting an if statement around the Read Error...

These are the patch works, that are really dangerous to have. Its usually expected to debug the code and find out whats the exact problem rather than adding a patch to cover up an existing bug.